# Парсинг названия файла Excel

Tags: excel, vba

такой вопрос:

Есть ряд файлов (книг Excel с данными) которые обрабатываются макросом
Названия файлов могут быть произвольными, но они в обязательном порядке содержат месяц и год (пример: Май20018 или Апрель_2018)

Подскажите, как можно извлечь название месяца из строки с названием файла в переменную.
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Май20018 - Вы не ошиблись? Строка *месяц_год* может иметь другой формат? Покажите код, которым получаете строку из названия файла или само название.

Comment: Для удобства программирования рекомендую все-таки ввести строгое именование файлов, лучше всего в американском формате: yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии, что ваши файлы именуются именно так, как вы писали, можно написать примитивную функцию, для извлечения текстовой части например:

```
Function getName(fileName As String) As String

Dim i, l As Integer
Dim c, outString As String

'обходим всю строку посимвольно
For i = 1 To Len(fileName)
    'извлекаем символ
    c = Mid(fileName, i, 1)
    'если символ не число или символ подчеркивания
    If Not (IsNumeric(c) Or c = "_") Then
        'добавляем к выходной строке
        outString = outString + c
    End If
Next
'возвращаем строку
getName = outString

End Function
```

`getName("Май20018")` - вернет `Май`
`getName("Апрель_2018")` - вернет `Апрель`

Answer (score 0):

Без циклов.

С использовнием функции листа:

```
Function fMonth_(sFName As String) As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(Mid$(sFName, 2, 2), "\нвеварпрайюнюлвгенктояек") / 2
    fMonth_ = Split("Январь Февраль Март Апрель Май Июнь Июль Август Сентябрь Октябрь Ноябрь Декабрь")(i - 1)
End Function
```

Шустрее:

```
Function fMonth_2(sFName As String) As String
    Select Case Left$(sFName, 3)
    Case "Янв": fMonth_ = "Январь"
    Case "Фев": fMonth_ = "Февраль"
    Case "Мар": fMonth_ = "Март"
    Case "Апр": fMonth_ = "Апрель"
    Case "Май": fMonth_ = "Май"
    Case "Июн": fMonth_ = "Июнь"
    Case "Июл": fMonth_ = "Июль"
    Case "Авг": fMonth_ = "Август"
    Case "Сен": fMonth_ = "Сентябрь"
    Case "Окт": fMonth_ = "Октябрь"
    Case "Ноя": fMonth_ = "Ноябрь"
    Case "Дек": fMonth_ = "Декабрь"
    End Select
End Function
```